# Is "class Xth" instead of "class X" ok?

Tags: phrases, subcontinental-english

Many people say, e.g., "Class Xth," "Category Xth," "Part Xth," "Street Xth," instead of "Class X," "Category X," "Part X," "Street X," respectively.

Is the former right?

Comment: Really? Could you give some example sentences where they're used? I can't think of one.

Comment: @MattЭллен, Its very common in India like : `I BELONG TO CATEGORY 2nd`. . .

Comment: you should specify what language you are talking about, there's no general rule for all existing languages

Comment: Is it right?  Perhaps it is right in India but not in England...

Comment: Fit the Second ... [Lewis Carroll](http://www.literature.org/authors/carroll-lewis/the-hunting-of-the-snark/chapter-02.html) ... [Hitchhiker's Guide](http://hitchhikers.wikia.com/wiki/Fit_the_Second)

Comment: @GEdgar Didn't get your statement. Could you explain?

Comment: This is Too Localised. Native speakers don't use the construction [Part Nth](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+part+third%2Cthe+third+part&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), regardless of whether non-native speakers in India have a tendency to do so. Given I can't find a single relevant instance of *"the **part second** is"* in Google Books, I frankly doubt they do very often anyway.

Comment: @GEdgar I like it, but it may be an exception :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally only if Xth precedes the type in-text. I would say 12th day, but never day 12th, in English. On the other hand, I would say day 12, but never 12 day. (specifically, 12 day would imply 12-day as in a count of twelve, involving the whole span of time)

Comment: The word order differences between English and other languages are common from what I've been told.

Answer (score 3):

In British English you would never say, "I belong to category 2nd."

You could say, "I belong to the second category," or,"I belong to category 2."

Comment: Good point about the rewording.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the former right?

Nope. It is "Xth class", "Xth category", "Xth part", "Xth street", but "Class X", "Category X", "Part X", "Street X".

Comment: There's a partial exception for dates: "June nineteenth" is common.  Some people say "June *the* nineteenth;" I don't care for this construct, personally, but it's also common.

Answer (score 0):

'Part the First' is common in the organisation of large treatises (e.g. [here](http://www.infidels.org/library/historical/thomas_paine/rights_of_man/part1.html)), perhaps to avoid confusion with 'Chapter 1'. It's fallen out of use recently, though, perhaps because fewer weighty treatises are being written.

Comment: Part the First is fairly archaic in most cases.